# Visual Basic 6.0: Compile Error When You Reopen a Project That Uses Implements

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6.0 project that contains the line

```
Implements IObjectSafety
```

I tried reopening this prject and compile it (.dll)

it throws an error like

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Basic
---------------------------
Compile error:

User-defined type not defined
---------------------------
```

tried to fix it using this url http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191207

but still no use

is there any help/ suggestions on this

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? Was it a problem with the DLL containing `IObjectSafety`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the class `IObjectSafety` defined? Is it part of your own project?

If it is defined in another project, make sure that you have referenced the project/DLL correctly & the class is public.

EDIT: Remove the line `Implements IObjectSafety` and type it again. Compile it & see if that works.

EDIT2: Could you remove all the code that is related to `IObjectSafety` and see if it compiles. And then add the `Implements` line at the top & add code progressively.

Does that help?

EDIT3: Here is the last thing, I could think of.

- Remove the reference to the DLL
- Remove the code that relates to `IObjectSafety`
- Save the project, Compile it, Close it.
- Open the project containing `IObjectSafety` class & compile it.
- Close this project.
- Open the project that will be using `IObjectSafety`
- Add the reference to the library containing `IObjectSafety`
- Compile the code

What happens?

Comment: Yes its defined in the same project

Comment: Correction: I meant the line "Implements IObjectSafety " is in the same project
the relevant references as mentioned in KB 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191207 are added

Comment: Remove that line & type it again. I assume that the class `IObjectSafety` is defined as public.

Comment: tried retyping the line Implements IObjectSafety
still not compiled

Comment: Where is the class IObjectSafety defined? Is it part of your own project?

If it is defined in another project, make sure that you have referenced the project/DLL correctly & the class is public.

EDIT: Remove the line Implements IObjectSafety and type it again. Compile it & see if that works.

EDIT2: Could you remove all the code that is related to IObjectSafety and see if it compiles. And then add the Implements line at the top & add code progressively. 
 
hmm it does not help that way too... very strange eventhough the references are available